# Linux: starttime field in /proc/[pid]/stat on earth use HZ(jiffies) or USER_HZ(_SC_CLK_TCK)

Tags: linux, proc

I wan't to measure the executing duration of a process outside this process on Linux. I found /proc/[pid]/state has a field named starttime which described to be "The time in jiffies the process started after system boot" on man page.

Also, I found /proc/uptime provides elapsed time ET in seconds since system boot. Theoretically I can acquire running time from these two files by 
running time = ET - starttime / (jiffies per second).

As to jiffies, I think it refers to CONFIG_HZ of kernel (250 on ubuntu 12.04) instead of USER_HZ (100 on ubuntu 12.04, acquired by "getconf CLK_TCK"), as described in http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch10lev1sec3. However, I test it and found that in fact the starttime uses USER_HZ on ubuntu 12.04. I was confused by this point. Could someone explained this to me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your `man` page was probably out-of-date at the time you retrieved it. Here's a [more current page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) which states the following:

> (22) *starttime*  `%llu`
>
> ```
>       The time the process started after system boot.  In
>       kernels before Linux 2.6, this value was expressed
>       in jiffies.  Since Linux 2.6, the value is expressed
>       in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)).
> ```

In older kernels (before Linux 2.6), the time really was represented in kernel jiffies. However, this behavior changed to now provide time in clock ticks -- jiffies scaled via the USER_HZ constant as you expect.